# Why do I get exceptions when trying to use .Net PowerShell Runspace to connect to my local Windows 10 machine?

Tags: .net, powershell, winrm, runspace

I'm trying to use **PowerShell** through .Net to connect to and and run some scripts on my **local machine**. I'm using Visual Studio 2019.
I keep getting exceptions when I attempt to open my **Runspace**.

**Consider the following code snippet:**

```
private SecureString ConvertToSecureString(string password)
{
    var secure = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password)
    {
        secure.AppendChar(c);
    }
    return secure;
}

private void foo()
{
    var credentials = new PSCredential("TestUser", ConvertToSecureString("TestPWD"));
    var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
    var addr = "192.168.1.123"  // "localhost", "."
    var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, addr, 5985, "/wsman", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", credentials, 15000);

    var testRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
    testRunSpace.Open();
}
```

I've tried using the IPAddress of my machine in addition to "localhost" and "."
I get the following exception messages:

- **IPAddress** -> "Connecting to remote server 192.168.1.121 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request..."
- "**localhost**", "**.**" -> "... Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic."

I've checked in PowerShell and the WinRM service is running on my local machine.

What am I doing wrong here.

Is there some configuration/setting which needs to be completed on my local machine in order for this to work?

Thanks, JohnB

Comment: You've tried running Visual Studio as admin?

Comment: @derekbaker783 - Tried that, but still same results.

Answer (score -1):

OK, so I figured it out.
I needed to make sure that I called "**Enable-PSRemoting**" to make sure remoting was enabled.
Then both "**localhost**" and "**.**" worked.